# How do I use the GDI+ blur effect on a .NET Bitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, system.drawing

I need to apply a blur to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.  The classes in `System.Drawing` are supposed to be wrappers around GDI+, so I'd I use the [GDI+ Blur effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534422(VS.85).aspx).  Is this possible, and if so, how?

Edit: I don't want to know how to write my own Blur effect, I want to know how to use the built-in GDI+ one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have developed a library on codeplex to do just this, the next version will have full legacy support for xp (with slower processing functions) for all effects, the current version only works on vista and above, you can find it at:

http://csharpgdiplus11.codeplex.com/

It comes with full source, so you can see how it's done.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be available anymore. Have you posted it anywhere else, like GitHub? Also, did you ever get around to the Legacy functions for XP?

Comment: Microsoft have added a download archive button now, so you can still get it. thanks.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is yet another suggestion that does not show you how to use GDI+ Blur, but I honestly cannot find it myself. I can see the reference in MSDN and the OS list for the Blur class in GDI+ only goes up to Win 2000. Perhaps it just doesn't exist anymore. If this helps at all, here is an EXCELLENT link on implimenting your own Blur in C#

http://home.scarlet.be/zoetrope/blur.htm

If that's not fast enough then give this a try:

http://www.cnblogs.com/dah/archive/2007/03/30/694527.html

...of course, you'll have to translate a little chinese.